How can I centralize a list of possible choices using Ansible roles argument_specs.yaml
Lets say that I have a role that uses meta/argument_specs.yaml, and I have a list of possible choices so that it can only be one of those values to be provided.
However I have more than one role that uses the same list of possible choices and I was wondering if it would be possible to centralize this list of possible choices that are going to be used for multiple roles.
Note: I also plan to use these roles in AWX.
meta/argument_specs.yaml
---
argument_specs:
  (...)
    options:
      domain:
        type: "str"
        required: true
        choices: ['domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com']
        description: "Domain to change to"

What I would like is to set this list of choices as a variable somewhere but not within each role so it could be centralized and then use it like this:
meta/argument_specs.yaml
---
argument_specs:
  (...)
    options:
      domain:
        type: "str"
        required: true
        choices: list_of_domains
        description: "Domain to change to"

I've also looked at another possibility which is to use a common role and then use it as a dependency, and that common role does the argument_specs with the list of choices.

See Understanding variable precedence. I'd keep such file in each role defaults/main/argument_specs.yaml (precedence 2.). I'd put 'centralized' argument_specs.yaml into a project group_vars/all/ directory (precedence 4. or 5.).
